# Do while loop keeps going after one of the or conditions is false

Tags: java, loops, intellij-idea, while-loop

This is the code I'm using:

```
 System.out.print("Naam van team 1: ");
    String team1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Naam van team 2: ");
    String team2 = input.nextLine();

    int[] puntenTeam1 = new int[6];
    int[] puntenTeam2 = new int[6];

    int gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1 = 0;
    int gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam2 = 0;

    int i = 0;


    do{
            System.out.println("Uitslag wedstrijd " + (i+1));
            System.out.print("\tAantal punten " + team1 +  ": ");
            puntenTeam1[i] = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("\tAantal punten " + team2 +  ": ");
            puntenTeam2[i] = input.nextInt();

            if (puntenTeam1[i] > puntenTeam2[i]){
                gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1++;
            }else if (puntenTeam2[i] > puntenTeam1[i]){
                gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam2++;
            }
            i++;

    } while(gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1 < 4 || gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam2 < 4);
```

If gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam2 or gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1 is higher than 4 it keeps looping... But it says it's false in debugging. Why is that the case?

Comment: What do you expect the `||` operator to do?

Comment: The `do`-`while` loop is executed as long as the `while`-condition is `true`, i.e. as long both `gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1` and `gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1` is `< 4`. If we want to stopf if either is `>= 4`, we should replace the `||` with an `&&`.

Comment: You condition is only false, if *both* values are greater than `4`

Comment: You have to use && instead of || this way when any one of the value reaches 4 or higher it will break the loop.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think "or" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

`while(gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1 < 4 || gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam2 < 4);`

to

`while(gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam1 < 4 && gewonnenWedstrijdenTeam2 < 4);`

or keeps looping if both are greater then 4 and a and loop keeps looping until one of the 2 goes above 4